# How do I set the default value of a TkInter widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Checkbutton that I need ticked as a default when I open the window. Setting the variable to the on value doesn't seem to work, so what should I do?
Here is a short, self contained example of what yields an unticked checkbox.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
class Sizzle(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Sizzle")
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        ifalphagrams=BooleanVar()
        b=Checkbutton(self, variable=ifalphagrams, onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
        b.grid(row=1,column=3 ,sticky=W)
        b.select()
def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("700x700+700+700")
    app = Sizzle(root)
    root.mainloop()  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `onvalue` and `offvalue` set the values associated with those states, they don't actually change the state. You an associate it with a `variable`, and ensure that that variable reflects the `onvalue`, or call `select` (see e.g. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm)

Comment: The box starts out checked on my machine, once I add all the proper imports and `mainloop`, etc. Maybe there's a problem in some of the code you've written that you haven't shown us. Please post a [short, self contained, runnable example](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits your problem.

Comment: It very well could be an import error - I'm just dipping into TK. Anyway, I've posted an example if you can help out.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - with Brian's help everything is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you're using a local variable to hold the reference to the `StringVar`, and it's getting garbage collected. When you prevent the variable from being garbage-collected your code works fine:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        ifalphagrams = StringVar()
        alp = Checkbutton(self, variable=ifalphagrams, onvalue='yes', offvalue='no')
        alp.grid(row=1,column=3, sticky=W)
        alp.select()
        self.ifalphagrams = ifalphagrams

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ahh yes, forgot about this little "feature".